# Передача action из скрипта

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Почему в файле не видит `$_POST['action']` из скрипта `action`?

```
         $('#address__form button').click(function() {
            var form_data = $("#address__form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            action: "address",
            url: "assets/ajax.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data) {
                var parse_data = JSON.parse(data);
                if(parse_data.err > 0){
                    $('.error_messages').detach();
                    $('#address__form').before('<div class="error_messages error"><ul>'+parse_data.error_message+'</ul></div>'); 
                }else{
                    if(parse_data.typea === 0){
                        $('.error_messages').detach();
                        $('.data-address').append(parse_data.item);
                    }
                    if(parse_data.typea == 1){
                        alert("Редактировано");
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(data) { // Данные не отправлены
                alert('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
            }
          });
    });
```

форма

```
            <form method="post" id="address__form">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
                <div class="address__name">
                    <input type="text" name="name_address" id="in_address" value="" placeholder="Название адреса">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="address_default" id="ad" value="1">
                        <label for="ad">Сделать основным</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="address__input">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Индекс">
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="address_city" value="" placeholder="Населенный пункт">
                    <input type="text" name="street" id="address_street" value="" placeholder="Улица">
                    <input type="text" name="home" value="" placeholder="Дом">
                    <input type="text" name="building" value="" placeholder="Корпус">
                    <input type="text" name="building1" value="" placeholder="Строение">
                    <input type="text" name="flat" value="" placeholder="Квартира">
                </div>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Примечания"></textarea>
                <button type="button" class="btn-dark">Сохранить</button>
            </form>
```

обработчик

```
          $formData = $_POST['formData'];
          $id =  $formData['id'];
          $name_address =  $formData['name_address'];
          $address_default =  $formData['address_default'];
          $postcode =  $formData['postcode'];
          $city =  $formData['city'];
          $street =  $formData['street'];
          $home =  $formData['home'];
          $building =  $formData['building'];
          $building1 =  $formData['building1'];
          $flat =  $formData['flat'];
          $message =  $formData['message'];
          $error_message = '';
          $output = [];
          $item = '';
          if (empty($name_address)) $error_message .= '<li>Укажите название адреса</li>';  
          if (empty($city)) $error_message .= '<li>Город указан некорректно. Проверьте правильность написания города или укажите ближайший город, если вы живете в населенном пункте, после чего в комментарии к заказу уточните Ваш адрес.</li>'; 
          if (empty($street)) $error_message .= '<li>Укажите, пожалуйста, название улицы</li>';
          if (empty($home)) $error_message .= '<li>Укажите, пожалуйста, номер дома</li>';
          if (empty($flat)) $error_message .= '<li>Укажите, пожалуйста, номер квартиры или поставьте прочерк.</li>';
          if (!empty($error_message)) {
             $output = array("err"=>1,"error_message"=>$error_message);
             echo json_encode($output);
          }else{
              if (!empty($id)){
                  $modx->query("UPDATE modx_user_address SET name_address = '".$name_address."',address_default='".$address_default."',postcode='".$postcode."',city='".$city."',street='".$street."',home='".$home."',building='".$building."',building1='".$building1."',flat='".$flat."',message='".$message."' WHERE id = ".$id."");
                   $count = $modx->exec($sql); // здесь будет количество строк
                    if ($count > 0){
                        $output = array("err"=>0,"typea"=>1,"id"=>$id);

                    }else $output = array("err"=>1,"typea"=>1,"id"=>$id,"error_message"=>"<li>Редактирование адреса не выполнено! Повторите попытку.</li>");

                    echo json_encode($output);
              }else{
                  $modx->query("INSERT INTO `modx_user_address`
                  (name_address, address_default, postcode, city,street,home,building,building1,flat,message,user_id) 
                  VALUES ('".$name_address."','".$address_default."', '".$postcode."','".$city."','".$street."','".$home."','".$building."','".$building1."','".$flat."','".$message."','".$modx->user->get('id')."')");
                  $id = $modx->lastInsertId();
                  if ($message) $comment = '<p class="comment">'.$message.'</p>';
                  if ($building) $commentb = ' корпус '.$building;
                  if ($building1) $comments = ' строение '.$building1;
                  if ($address_default == 1) $default = 'Основной';
                  $item = '
                    <div class="item">
                            <div class="header">
                                <p class="title">'.$name_address.'</p>
                                <span>'.$default.'</span>
                                <div class="data-btn">
                                    <button class="edit" data-id="'.$id.'"></button>
                                    <button class="delete" data-id="'.$id.'"></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="body">
                                <p>'.$postcode.' '.$city.' '.$street.' д.'.$home.' '.$commentb.' '.$comments.' кв.'.$flat.'</p>
                                '.$comment.'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  ';
                  $output = array("err"=>0,"typea"=>0,"id"=>$id,"item"=>$item);
                  echo json_encode($output);
              }

      }
```

Comment: А покажите форму. Не совсем понятно какой acton вы отправляете и что хотите получить

Comment: добавил форму в вопрос

Comment: У метода `$.ajax` нет опции `action`. Зато есть такой атрибут у элемента `<form>`, и похоже именно он вам и нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть документацию по [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), то вы не найдете в нем параметра action. Чтобы корректно передать этот параметр или добавьте в форму

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="address">
```

или в скрипте измените параметр data следующим образом:

```
data: {
   action: 'address',
   formData: form_data
}
```

И у вас в $_POST['action'] будет ваш экшен, данные из формы будут в $_POST['formData']

Comment: а как их извлечь из $_POST['formData']?

Comment: Как из обычного массива $_POST['formData']['postcode'] и т.д. Или для упрощения сделайте вот так $formData = $_POST['formData'] - и далее обращайтесь к данным через переменную - $formData['postcode'], $formData['city'] и т.д

Comment: $id =  $_POST['formData']['id']; и оно пустое, а если я делаю так if (isset($id)) то редактируем  и он не видит что id пуст и все ровно редактирует

Comment: Используйте для проверки !empty($id) - потому что isset проверит установлена ли у вас переменная $id, но не проверит содержимое, а учитывая что вы объявили $id, то isset будет возвращать true

Comment: почему то все ровно пропускает

Comment: добавил обработчик в вопросе

Comment: Как то очень подозрительно. А что возвращает если только $id принтануть? Вы уверены что $formData['id'] пустое?

Comment: возвращает почему-то i

Comment: Значит активно ищем что на фронте нам прокидывает туда i. И попробуйте в скрипте для отправки формы использовать serializeArray() вместо serialize - чтобы наверняка

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то ключ action это какой вызвать метод

Т.е. вот эквивалент `<form action="uploadPhoto.php" method="POST">`

А значит в объекте $_POST не будет упоминания об `action` (если правильно помню, он будет в URL)

Comment: указанные екшен не относится к вопросу, потому что в аякс скрипте проставлен url - что как раз и указывают в action формы. В вопросе параметр action рассматривается как "действие" - например из какой формы отправили и я так полагаю на беке автор хочет узнать из какой формы отправили запрос, чтобы сориентироваться как обработать данные. Но это мое понимание могу ошибаться

Comment: Согласен, скорей всего, я не правильно понял суть вопроса и исходил из кода, который был предоставлен)